# How do I view raw SQL of the query generated by asyncpg?

Tags: python, asyncpg

As it is said in [asyncpg Usage](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html), I can use `$n` pattern for the arguments and execute a query this way, for example:

```
result = await conn.fetchval("SELECT $1", 42)
```

In this case the raw SQL would be `SELECT 42`. How do I get this raw text with an asyncpg function before execution? I am asking this is because I want to log queries in my project before they are applied.

```
query_tpl = "SELECT $1"
values = (42,)

sql = what_is_here(query_tpl, *values)  # <- ???
print(sql)  # Must be "SELECT 42"

result = await conn.fetchval(query_tpl, *values)
```